# IsBadStringPtr alternative

Tags: c++, c, winapi, pointers

I have inherited the code that uses the function

```
#define CHECK_CSTRING_PTR(a,b)          (!IsBadStringPtrA(a,b))
#define INTERNAL_CHECK_CSTRING_PTR(a)   CHECK_CSTRING_PTR(a,1)
TCHAR CopyString (const TCHAR * szCopyMe )
{
    char * szResult = NULL;
    size_t tLength = 0;
    /*check the string pointer*/
    if ( INTERNAL_CHECK_TSTRING_PTR ( szCopyMe ) )
    {
        //blah blah
    }
 }
```

I have read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366714(v=vs.85).aspx that IsBadStringPtr should not be used anymore.

What alternative should I use?

CanI simply use?

```
if( szCopyMe != NULL )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As they say, you can't validate a pointer. In your case you have two options for handling bad pointers :

### 1. Let the bad pointer crash the program

That's the solution recommended by Raymond Chen at the end of this MSDN blog article:

[IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

In that case, your fix is correct.

### 2. Catch the exception using SEH

If you don't want to stop the application, [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can prevent the crash, but according to some, it's not a good idea:

[Structured Exception Handling Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/10/228068.aspx).

Comment: Agreed on SEH for runtime errors being a bad idea in general, but I've seen it helpfully used to save a "rescue backup" of open documents. Basically, a segfault should always cause a crash. It just doesn't have to crash *instantly*.

Comment: Agreed, it's just for most people (myself included) exception handling equates to sweeping everything under the rug.

Comment: Meh, the rug that the user or you need to look under to diagnose the cause of the crash, usually.  One big reason that Java ate C++'s lunch.  SEH is primarily useful to *report* crashes, not to ignore them.

Comment: The advantage of a hard crash is that Windows Error Reporting can report the problem to you; you don't need to collect the crash data yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can really use that doesn't have the same issues.

The problem with `IsBadStringPtr` is that it works by scanning through memory and seeing if something breaks. But dereferencing random pointers, while safe for the OS, can be quite unsafe for your process, because it can unguard guard pages. And even if the pointer is "valid", that's no guarantee that the data it points to is a string, let alone the string you were expecting. And then there's potential race conditions on top of things.

If a string pointer is dereferenced, and points to invalid memory, your program should crash, because then you know there's a problem and can fix it. And if you've set up a situation where you don't know for sure whether your string pointer is "real", then you've already lost. Your OS will protect one program from another, but it won't protect a program from itself. You need to build that safety through the design of your program.